# Java: Unable to read file using FileReader

Tags: java, compiler-errors, java.util.scanner, filereader, java-io

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Airline {
        private static final int MAX_COLUMNS = 6;
        private static final int MAX_ROWS = 30;
        public String[][] seatArray = new String[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS];
        public double[][] priceArray = new double[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS];
        File file = new File("seatPrices.txt");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(fr).useDelimiter("\\s*:\\s*");
}
```

Where it shows

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
```

I get the error message:

"Default constructor cannot handle exception type FileNotFoundException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor"

I don't know where exactly to place seatPrices.txt, so I placed it in my /src folder.

I'm **very** new to coding, so detailed help would be much appreciated.

Comment: where is the seatPrices.txt file is

Comment: @ASdi: that has nothing to do with his error. His is a compilation error, not a run-time exception.

Comment: Original poster, this question has been asked many times before. Please see some of the [duplicates that can easily be found](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+Default+constructor+cannot+handle+exception+type+FileNotFoundException).

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels sure, my mistake

Comment: @ASdi: no problem, but it's quite possible that the issue you bring up may be his *next* problem, once he is able to get his code to compile.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm looking at the various other people who had similar problems, but I am completely lost with the throw-catch issues and people's codes are vastly too complicated to even understand the problems.

Comment: Read the tutorial on exceptions. You can find it [here, first hit](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=tutorial%20java%20exceptions). It will tell you all that you need to know and then some.

Comment: The first step if view what is the current default folder. try using it: System.out.print(System.getProperty("user.dir"));